# I want to get rid of Red squiggly lines in my NextJS API

Tags: typescript, api, next.js

I created a API endpoint using Typescript in NextJS. The API is working fine but I want to get rid of the Red squiggly lines beneath my code. I tried a lot but I am unable to solve this problem. I am still learning Typescript so your help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
type Data = {
  prompt: string;
  success: boolean;
  data: string;
  error: unknown;
};

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const { prompt, size } = req.body;

  const imageSize =
    size === "Small" ? "256x256" : size === "Medium" ? "512x512" : "1024x1024";

  try {
    const response = await openai.createImage({
      prompt,
      n: 1,
      size: imageSize,
    });

    const imageUrl = response.data.data[0].url;

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: imageUrl,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: "The image could not be generated",
    });
  }
}
```

These are the red squiggly lines I am getting:

[image: These are the red squiggly lines I am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the lines, it will show you the error it is seeing.
[image: Type Error]

Your "Data" type has all properties required. You can correct this by either pressing "quick fix" to add the additional properties, or make them optional in the type defenition.

```
    type Data = {
  prompt?: string;
  success?: boolean;
  data?: string;
  error?: unknown;
};
```